# How do I get rid of the text from produced by the except?

Tags: python

This is a calculator written in python 3.7 and it works PERFECTLY fine but I just want to have a little improvement so I will ask you, from line 0 to 6, I made a `try except` block and looped it with `while True`. This will make the user of this calculator notice "You entered an invalid number". While it does work fine according to the result of the command, for the sake of simplicity, I would like to make the computer only say "enter_first_number" again after the user types in an invalid number at the first. So I want to get rid of the "invalid_number". I could just type in `print()` instead of `print(invalid_number)`, but I don't like how it looks like the blank that is produced by a that. Can anyone solve this problem?

code:

```
while True:
    try:
        num1 = float(input("enter_first_number_&_press_enter: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("invalid_number")
op = input("enter_an_operator: ")
while True:
    if op == "+":
        break
    elif op == "-":
        break
    elif op == "*":
        break
    elif op == "/":
        break
    else:
        print("invalid_operator")
        op = input("enter_an_operator: ")
while True:
    try:
        num2 = float(input("enter_second_number_&_press_enter: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("invalid_number")
if op == "+":
    print(num1 + num2)
elif op == "-":
    print(num1 - num2)
elif op == "*":
    print(num1 * num2)
elif op == "/":
    print(num1 / num2)
```

Comment: You should try to keep your question short. Don't write a novel.

Comment: Then people think my question is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

> So I want to get rid of the "invalid_number".

Replace the print statement inside the `except` with `pass`, which does nothing.

```
while True:
    try:
        num1 = float(input("enter_first_number_&_press_enter: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the print statement with `pass`.

For example:

```
try:
    num1 = float(input("enter_first_number_&_press_enter: "))
    break
except ValueError:
    pass
```

The `pass` command tells python to continue running without doing anything.

Otherwise, replacing the print statement with `print('', end='')` will print out an empty string with no newline character at the end.